# how to get the values of specified date range?

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve today's values from the table, in my table i have created_at columns, which is a timestamp automatically assigned when a row is inserted. I also have a send_at column where i manually insert datetime, when i query send_at with a range it works, but when i query created_at column i get nothing back.

```
  $campaigns = SmsCampaign::whereBetween('created_at', array('2017-03-20 12:00:00','2017-03-20 23:59:00'))->paginate(10);

        return view('sms_campaign.smscampaign')->with('campaigns', $campaigns);
```

[image]

model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SmsCampaign extends Model
{


protected $table = 'sms_campaign';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
//public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = [ 'campaign_name', 'content', 'phone_no_list',  'send_time', 'status', 'merchant_id', 'send_type'];




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Carbon instances:

```
SmsCampaign::whereBetween('created_at', [
        Carbon::parse('2017-03-20 12:00:00'),
        Carbon::parse('2017-03-20 23:59.00')
    ])->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thx Alexey Mezenin for the answer, i tried i still get nothing

Comment: the same code works for the "send_at" column but not for the 'created_at

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin the table is created manually and connected by the model, please check my question i have attached the table for you

Comment: `created_at` should be `timestamp` too.

Comment: yes it was timestamp before too, i just changed it again to test. still nothing :(

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin btw i figured out that the timezone of my "created_at" column is not the same as my location do you think im getting this problem because it is not the correct timezone?

Comment: @Mikethetechy the code looks fine and it should work when `$timestamps = false` is commented and `created_at` is `timestamp`. And yes, the problem could be in the timezone.

Comment: do you know how i can change the time zone? in phpmyadmin

Comment: i found that in app.php i can change the timezone

Comment: thanks a lot bro. Figured out .. i just had to change the time zone